# backbone collection fetch doesn't fire reset()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

This is my view for a collection

```
var mssg = mssg || {};

mssg.MessagesView = Backbone.View.extend({

el: '#messages',

initialize: function() {
    this.collection.fetch();
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
},

render : function() {
    this.$el.html('');
    this.collection.each(function( item ) {
        this.renderMessage( item );
    }, this );
    return this;
},

renderMessage : function( item ) {
    var messageView = new mssg.MessageView({
        model : item
    });
    this.$el.append( messageView.render().el );
}

});
```

this is the collection

```
var mssg = mssg || {};

mssg.Messages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : mssg.Message,
    url : 'messages'
});
```

and this is how it is initialized:

```
var mssg = mssg || {};

$(function() {
    new mssg.MessagesView({
        collection : new mssg.Messages()
    });
});
```

The problem is that the `render` function bound to `reset` doesn't fire after the ajax fetch request.

If I bind it to `add` it works.
I tried binding `all` to a debuggin function and it says that the `sync` event is called alongside the `add` for every item.

Comment: Could you try this.collection.fetch({reset: true}) ?

Comment: @nikoshr thanks that worked! I thought it was implied tho?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you check backbone [change log](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog), you'll see that the way fetch is handled changed in 1.0:

> Renamed Collection's "update" to set, for parallelism with the similar
>   model.set(), and contrast with reset. It's now the default updating
>   mechanism after a fetch. If you'd like to continue using "reset", pass
>   `{reset: true}`

So, to trigger a reset event, you now have to use

```
this.collection.fetch({reset: true})
```

Comment: cool thanks, it's a new app so I simply switched to the new default (`set`)

Answer (score 0):

in backbone 1.0, you have to trigger reset by hand:

```
youColloection.fetch({reset: true});
```