# Backbone : view doesn't update (reset event)

Tags: javascript, events, backbone.js, view

I'm currently using BackboneJS to get data from my database with a backbone model.

The problem is that my app is not firing my reset event and my data are not displayed on the screen even if my fetch is well executed.
If I execute app.messages.toJSON() in my console, my data are returned as demanded.

Do you have any idea about it ? Here is my code

```
var app = window.app = {};

// APP HERE

// Model

app.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : 'messages'
});

app.message = new app.Message;

// Collection

app.Messages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : app.Message,
    url : 'messages'
});

// Views

app.messages = new app.Message(); 
app.messages.fetch();

app.ListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template : Handlebars.compile($('#template-list').html()),

    initialize : function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        //this.collection.on('reset', this.render); 
    },

    render : function(){
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            collection : this.collection.toJSON()
        }));
        return this;
    }

});
```

I'm breaking my teeth on it.

Simon

EDIT

After all this code I have

```
app.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '*path' : 'home'
    },
    home: function(){
        this.views = {};
        this.views.list = new app.ListView({
            collection : app.messages
        });
        $('#list-shell').empty().append(this.views.list.render().el);
    }
});

app.router = new app.Router();
Backbone.history.start({pushState : true});
Backbone.emulateJSON = true;
```

Comment: Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603107/backbone-collection-fetch-doesnt-fire-reset/15603449#15603449 ?

Comment: Or do you create your view after the fetch (which may have concluded by that point)?

Comment: I don't see where you are instantiating your `ListView`.  Here you are just defining the `ListView` "class".

Comment: @nikoshr : already try, doesn't works :/

Comment: If I use an object created inside the file, everything works, i'm pretty sure it comes from the reset but I don't know where is the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

`app.messages = new app.Message();` I guess this is only a mistake you made while writing the question.

As for the question itself, if you're using Backbone 1.0, you'll have to use the `reset flag` if you want a `reset event` fired.
Furthermore, if the piece of code you added really is **after** the first one, you're fetching your data **before** creating the Router, therefore the view. Even if the fetching method is asynchronous, you're not controlling what you're doing here.