# can't catch Backbone Collection reset event

Tags: web-services, backbone.js, collections

I've stumbled across something quite strange

I'm fetching a collection, and listening on the reset event, but somehow the event is lost

I have this minimal example:

```
$(function() {
  var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
  collection.url = 'http://localhost:9000/api/Usuario';
  collection.on('reset', function() {
    console.log('collection reset!');
  });
  collection.fetch();
});
```

Inspecting the network I can see that the request is seuccessful, and the web service returns json data

But there's no way that the cosole.log('collection reset!') callback is executed.

There must be something really silly that I'm missing...

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603107/backbone-collection-fetch-doesnt-fire-reset/15603449#15603449

Comment: You are right! now I'll ask how can I catch the event of a collection that finished fetching the data

Comment: You can override the default parse method present in Backbone.Collection class to return/manipulate data in whichever way you want.

Comment: @opensas There's a `sync` event

Answer (score 1):

From [Backbone documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)

```
It uses set to (intelligently) merge the fetched models, unless you pass {reset: true},
```

So I guess, Using this will solve your problem.

```
collection.fetch({
    reset: true,
    success: function() {
        // Do Something
        // This is called when all add, remove and update operations have been done
    }
});
```

Comment: yea, I realized about it, I just wonder what would be the default way yo do it. It's strange that they don trigger a "fetched" event or something like that after all the changes (add, destroy, updates) have been issued

Comment: I think there is no need of 'fetched event' when we have successhandler. Check this http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch You can define a successhandler and in that you can do whatever you want. Updating my code. Check it.