# Which event is been triggered on backbone collection fetch?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I am using backbone 1.0.0, and reading here that after a fetch
[backbone collection fetch doesn't fire reset()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15603107/backbone-collection-fetch-doesnt-fire-reset)
a collection set is been called to "smart" update collection

which event is been triggered after the "smart update" I tried "change" but didn't worked. 
I had to call the fetch with 
    `{reset: true}`
and use the "add" event but I don't really want to reset the collection.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `fetch()` also calls `set()` once the data returns, which then fires a "smart" update. This smart update should trigger a `change` event. Furthermore, this behavior should exist in 1.0.0.

Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

A 'sync' event is fired after a successful fetch(). I understand 'reset' is fired before the fetch().